# Load a text file paragraph into a string without libraries

Tags: python, string, file, txt

sorry if this question may look a bit dumb for some of you but i'm totally a beginner at programming in Python so i'm quite bad and got a still got a lot to learn.
So basically I have this long text file separated by paragraphs, sometimes the newline can be double or triple to make the task more hard for us so i added a little check and looks like it's working fine so i have a variable called "paragraph" that tells me in which paragraph i am currently.
Now basically i need to scan this text file and search for some sequences of words in it but the newline character is the worst enemy here, for example if i have the string = "dummy text" and i'm looking into this:

```
"random questions about files with a dummy
 text and strings

 hey look a new paragraph here"
```

As you can see there is a newline between dummy and text so reading the file line by line doesn't work. So i was wondering to load directly the entire paragraph to a string so this way i can even remove punctuation and stuff more easly and check directly if those sequences of words are contained in it.
All this must be done without libraries.
However my piece of code of paragraph counter works while the file is being read, so if uploading a whole paragraph in a string is possible i should basically use something like "".join until the paragraph increases by 1 because we're on the next paragraph? Any idea?

Comment: What is your variable `paragraph`? Is your `"random ... here" is a paragraph?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi I've not posted the code here but the variable paragraph is just a integer that increases each time finds more words after 1 or more newspaces. For example in this case from "random" to "strings" is paragraph 1, then from "hey" to "here" is paragraph 2

Comment: More than 1 newlines separate paragraphs? And what you want to do is find sequences of words inside a paragraph?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Sometimes can happen that the newline can be more than 2 in order to make this whole thing more complex (it's a university project). Basically yes, i need to find if exactly those sequences of words are in that paragraph (in sequence obviously, if "dummy" and "text" weren't next to each other the output should be false)

Comment: I think you can just `join` when you encounter an empty line?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Damn didn't think about that, gonna try a piece of code and see if works

Comment: Please check my answer as well...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need to think it in a difficult way. Here is a very commonly used pattern for this kind of problems.

```
paragraphs = []
lines = []
for line in open('text.txt'):
    if not line.strip():  # empty line
        if lines:
            paragraphs.append("".join(lines))
            lines = []
    else:
        lines.append(line)
if lines:
    paragraphs.append("".join(lines))
```

If a `strip`ped line is empty, you encounter the second `\n` and it means that you have to `join` previous lines to a paragraph.

If you encounter the 3rd `\n`, you must not `join` again so remove your previous lines (`lines = []`). In this way, you will not `join` the same paragraph again.

To check the last line, try this pattern.

```
f = open('text.txt')
line0 = f.readline()
while True:
    # do what you have to do with the previous line, `line0`
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:    # `line0` was the last line
        # do what you have to do with the last line
        break
    line0 = line
```

Comment: With a few changes but keeping this concept I integrated this into my program but there's only 1 issue: when i reach the end of the file (the last paragraph) since there's no newline it just ignores the .join at that point, is there any way to understand if i'm at the last row of a file? I've opened it like this:
    for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):

Comment: In my code snippet. The last `if` outside the `for` loop is to `join` the last paragraph. The last element of the list returned by `readlines()` is the last line. After the last line `readline()` returns `None`.

Comment: Yes however i had to do some changes to integrate this in my program and couldn't take that last part, just did another piece of code before this to read the file and save the last line of it and added an "if" during the paragraph checks that in case line == last_line just do the .join, after i'll make this whole thing work i'll start the optimization process

Comment: @Krist I added another pattern for your requirement. Please check it and accept it if it works! :)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Still stuck because of the complexity of this exercise but i hope to find a way through it, I underestimated the "words in sequence" part and words that simply are in the file singularly are in my output... maybe tomorrow will ask for more help because this is driving me crazy, it's been more than 1 week already

Comment: @Krist Any more questions?

Comment: I got a question about the list.pop(), I'm trying to figure out how to clean my list from stuff that doesn't exist at all in a single paragraph so i was thinking about using a common cycle `for i in range(len(list))` and in case the element is not found i just use list.pop(i). But i was wondering how can i make sure to make the "for" cycle from the same index? Let's say i removed list[0] because wasn't in the string, now list[1] has moved to list[0] but i need to check that again

Comment: @Krist Very simple and important solution: loop **backward**.

Comment: so basically i just do i -= 1?

Comment: @Krist `for i in range(len(list) - 1, -1, -1):`, haha. If `list[i]` is empty, pop it out and go to `list[i - 1]`

Comment: Regarding the code for the last line that you gave me yesterday, i just noticed through debug that for some reason it just passes from first line of the txt to second without going trough the conditions, is there any way to take the first line into conditions aswell? This is a piece of code maybe you can understand better, is a bit written in a quite confused way: https://pastebin.com/RrDDbDu9

Comment: @Krist You do not need both of `while` and `for`.

Comment: Hey again me, sorry if i'm bothering you but this stuff is driving me crazy i need desperate help. I'm writing the piece of code that is supposed to check if all words in my list of sentences are contained in my string and i'm at this point: https://pastebin.com/bu7A7ZKx
Basically it keeps giving me an error `list index out of range at gr_clean_word = words[c].strip(".,:;!?")` but why?
The other thing i'm worried about is that i can't make the continue statement pass into next word if it find any translation and instead if any other translation happen to be wrong will delete the word anyway

Comment: @Krist Why do you do `c -= 1`. `c` is decrementing from `len(words) -1` to `-1`. If you additionally subtract 1 from `c`, `c` will be out of `range`. Please accept my answer if helpful!

Comment: removed them both, now it says words.pop(c) index out of range

Comment: @Krist Hope you to consider accept the answer or reject it. Anyway, if you use another `for` loop in sides the main loop, you could `pop` more than you need.

Comment: I accepted it but i'm below 15 of reputation so that's recorded but not shown until i reach 15 of reputation i think :\

Comment: @Krist Thanks, buddy! Solved your issue?

Comment: With debug I tried to understand what's happening and basically the 2nd problem that i explained above is the cause of all of this: the cycle should just work fine (since is backwards) but it basically deletes a word each time translation in dict has not been found (pastebin from line 24) but what i need is to check if any translation can be found in dict items, if yes he just should do nothing and only if none of items can be a translation delete the word and go back and cycle next word (line 13 of the pastebin)

Comment: @Krist In such a pattern ("there exists" or "at least one" condition), how about to `pop` then `break`?

Comment: the break worked perfectly, thanks for the tip. The "exists" is something included in .os library and we're not allowed to use it so i need to figure out another way to make the word stay in the list if at least 1 item in dictionary corresponds

Comment: @Krist I meant `∃`. For "there exists at least one which satisfies the condition" problem, you can break right after the condition is met. It is also good for performance.

Comment: Played a bit with "break" and "continue" and look like it's working just fine now!
https://pastebin.com/jsEGMXQE

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. It is very short and elegant:

```
with open('dummy text.txt') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
print(data)#prints out the file
```

The output is:

```
"random questions about files with a dummy text and strings hey look a new paragraph here"
```

Comment: This replaces \n and the issue of \n during the check is solved but i still need to keep track of the paragraph counter, it's part of the return value, any idea?

Comment: I did not get how your code works. I f possible could you share the code you wrote to output the para. Maybe then I can find a way to connect them. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the newline character. Here is an example from a different problem.

```
data = open('resources.txt', 'r')
book_list = []
for line in data:
    new_line = line.rstrip('\n')
    book_list.append(new_line)
```

Comment: Yes the .rstrip was something i was definitively going to do i just need to figure out how to merge together all the lines of 1 paragraph to a string and after i've done all the operations that needed to be done load another paragraph to the string and so on until the file is finished

Comment: @Krist Let's say you have a string called my_string which may or may not be empty.  You just add my_string += new_line inside the for loop and it will build your string.